# Use date entered in different cells as single variable for comparison

Tags: vba, date, excel

I would like to ask for a way to take the values of 3 cells as input, then combine them into a date for use with my code.

The code that wont work is is here:

```
ph2bdate = DateValue(.Range("K6").Value, .Range("K5").Value, .Range("K4").Value) + 1
ph2blastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For ph2bsteps = 8 To ph2blastrow Step 1
    If Year(.Cells(ph2bsteps, 1).Value) = Year(ph2bdate) _
    And Month(.Cells(ph2bsteps, 1).Value) = Month(ph2bdate) _
    And Day(.Cells(ph2bsteps, 1).Value) = Day(ph2bdate) Then
    ph2brangeupper = ph2bsteps
    Exit For
    End If
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `DateSerial` instead of `DateValue`

Comment: In fact, looking at your For loop, you don't need `ph2bdate` at all. You can directly use `.Range("K6").Value` instead of `Year(ph2bdate)` if that cell contains the year... And similarly for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

MeThinks that Siddharth Rout's changes are on the right track in that we don't need to use Year/Month/Day on the right hand inside the FOR loop.  But also we don't need to have Year/... on the left hand side nor refer back to the Range either -- we can just compare the two dates --

```
ph2bdate = DateSerial(.Range("K6").Value, .Range("K5").Value, .Range("K4").Value) + 1
ph2blastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For ph2bsteps = 8 To ph2blastrow Step 1
    If .Cells(ph2bsteps, 1).Value  = ph2bdate
        ph2brangeupper = ph2bsteps
        Exit For
    End If
Next ph2bsteps
```

Do we always have a +1 date in some row, or do we need to compare  >=

Comment: Thank you for this correction sir. It works well with my code. The thing with my code is that it contains time as well, that's why I extracted the Year Values first before comparing.But I will also try it out and see what happens.